# Update an Id when using that Id to join on in Oracle MERGE

Tags: sql, oracle

**Table 1: PERSON**

```
ID, colx...

10
20
30
40
50
60
```

**Table 2: TBL_MERGE**

```
ID, colx..., Old_ID

 10, ...,    null
 20, ...,    null
300, ...,    30
 40, ...,    null
 50, ...,    null
600, ...,    60
```

I want to update table 1 (PERSON) with table 2 (TBL_MERGE) based on this criteria.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
IF tbl_merge.old_id IS NOT NULL AND tbl_merge.old_id = person.id THEN
    person.id = tbl_merge.id
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to `UPDATE` the data in `PERSON`, why would you want to use a `MERGE` statement rather than an `UPDATE` statement?  Is there a situation where you would also want to do an `INSERT` into `PERSON` from `TBL_MERGE` if there is no matching row in `PERSON`?

Comment: I was trying the MERGE because there can multiple records and I thought that's what I need. And no, I don't have to worry about inserts.

Comment: MERGE can sometimes be useful for update-only situations (eg. when the query is complex, you might not want to have to specify it twice in an UPDATE statement), but in this case not possible because you're updating the column which is being used as the identifier for the match. You'll need to use an UPDATE as per @Declan_K's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE person p set ID = (SELECT t.ID FROM tbl_merge t where t.old_id = p.ID)
WHERE EXISTS (Select 1 FROM tbl_merge t where t.old_id = p.ID)
```

Comment: You'd have to change that for the case when PERSON.ID doesn't match a value in TBL_MERGE.OLD_ID as it would try to update PERSON.ID with NULL.

Comment: Updated to eliminate the posiiblity of updating to `NULL`

Comment: I get missing expression when I try to do this.

Comment: WHERE EXIST*S* - needs an S.

Comment: "table or view does not exist"

Also, = (SELECT m.ID..)  did you mean t.ID? If so, still same error.

Comment: Sorry, very sloppy post. I replaced the m.ID with t.ID and changed EXIST to EXISTS. Should work now.

Comment: Are your tables called **exactly** `person` and `tbl_merge`? If not you need to update the script to match your table names.

Comment: This works thanks a lot Declan_K! Can you explain to me the WHERE EXISTS part please? I don't understand what's happening there as well as the SELECT 1 part... Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I can't upvote the answer because I'm new to the site but again everything looks good, appreciate it.

Comment: You can accept the answer, so that folks know your question has been resolved.